# Bumptop - What's the relations with physics

Tags: algorithm, desktop, physics

Along with all buzz talks about the wonderful [Bumptop](http://bumptop.com) desktop environment, Im getting this question now. What is the relation with Physics and Bumptop techniques. Basically, I am interested in learning the techniques/algorithms followed in this desktop environment. For example,

1. Collision Detection -- is used when one icon is about to collide on other one.

Any other known techniques?

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of Bumptop. So sad. Yet another grad student wasted on reinventing the 1980s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably uses a quite common [rigid body dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics) simulator as used in (simple/older) computer games. If you want to play with one yourself, have a look at [Open Dynamics Engine](http://www.ode.org/).

Comment: Also, in not so simple computer games ;)

Comment: Don't they use soft body engines today?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it uses mechanics (the branch of physics that describes motion) to determine/calculate the outcome of object interaction.

I remember seeing a very early demo of this months ago - it looks very impressive!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks as though it's using friction and velocity as well. The friction slows the animations down - if it didn't then things would just fly out of the way. Velocity is used to have things move at speed in certain directions.

Answer (score 0):

More info here

[BumpTop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BumpTop)

> Extensive use of physics effects like
>   **bumping** and **tossing** is applied to
>   documents when they interact, for a
>   more realistic experience.